# SVG Path Intersection in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

[image]So, I'm trying to find the intersection of an SVG path with an another path or svg element. I have tried some APIs like https://github.com/amatiash/svg.intersections.js#module_SVGIntersections and https://github.com/signavio/svg-intersections. But i think `svg.intersection.js` requires SVG objects but i have SVG predefined in my html page so i am not able to use functions of API. Is there anyway i can find intersection easily.
I have also added an image to make it clear like i want to stop these intersection between black and green, red and green stripes(these are svg paths) also i will be really helpfully if you can tell me any way to stop the intersection of the obj(.png) and svg path( i.e., battery and green line).

Comment: I woud like to see a simple example. Depending on what you have  you may clip one path with the other-

Comment: i have updated the post please check :)